# How can I make water flow around a corner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am redoing the water transportation of my slime farm, I had problems with big slimes getting stuck around the corner.

The way I used to do it was using half-slabs, but not I want to try the stair method. Plus I want to keep it as simple as possible, but I am running into problems.

Screenshot:

[image]

Basically I want the slimes to get to point D. I do not want to move point D because of the endpoint, it is important that it starts there. All before that can be changed.

I dug out the blocks at point C and placed water source blocks flowing to point D, but the problem I am having is that it flows to point B. This makes B a dead point.

I want to go around the corner as simple as possible, and preferably not using half slabs, because the big slimes get stuck there. I hope there is a way with just corectly placing the source blocks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is have point A higher than point D, and then have the water go down a level  before changing level. So from the side it will look like this:

```
8 7 6 5 4 S
B B B B B 8 7 6

8 = Water source
B = Block
S = Sign
```

This way the water cannot flow backwards and you don't have to move the slimed upwards.